# Rally, custom grid: how to check for logged in user

Tags: rally

Is it possible to have queries in a custom grid that check for the current logged in user?

e.g. (Owner = LOGGED_IN_USER)

If not, how to go about building personalized dashboards that the team can share?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special {user} token that can be used to accomplish what you want.

```
(Owner = {user})
```

More information on writing advanced queries can be found in the rally help: http://help.rallydev.com/use-grid-app-queries